# Finding the equation of 4 circles given 3 tangents, one of which is oblique

Tags: linear-algebra, circles

The question is to find the equation of the four circles tangent to the x-axis, the y-axis and the line $x+y=2$. I have drawn out a diagram and have identified the 4 circles but I am stuck on how to find their equations.

Comment: Since you have identified the 4 circles, you should know where the points of tangency are, etc.  That is enough to write down the equations, no?

Comment: maybe thats the problem. How do I find point of tangency?

Comment: So what exactly do you mean by "have identified the 4 circles"?

Comment: I drew the diagram and the appropriate circles. One is enclosed and the other 3 are external.

Comment: I think I need to just work out the POC but I'm not sure how to do that when nothing else is given.

Comment: I'm not sure of what I'm going to say but I think it should work. You can deduce that the centers of the circles are along $y=x$ and $y=-x$ and with $ |x| = |y| = R$ where $R$ is the radius of the circle. Then you can parametrise the circles and realise which point on the circle will be tangent to the line. With that you should be able to get the radii for each circle using the line equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this.  For example, if you know about incircle and excircles of triangles, then just follow that construction or other known facts (such as: the point of tangency of the excircle $\Gamma_A$ are distance $s=\frac12(a+b+c)$ from $A$, the in-/ex-centres are on the angle bisector, the inradius $r=\Delta/s$, exradius $r_A=\Delta/(s-a)$, etc.).

However, you can also do it purely algebraically:
A circle $x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ is tangent to $Ax+By+C=0$ if and only if solving the simultaneous equation gives repeated roots.  Eliminating $x$ (assuming $A\neq 0$, otherwise change $x\leftrightarrow y$) gives
$$
(A^2+B^2) y^2 + (A^2 E-ABD+2BC) y + A^2 F - A C D + C^2=0
$$
and we want the discriminant to be zero:
$$
(A^2 E-ABD+2BC)^2-4(A^2+B^2)(A^2 F - A C D + C^2)=0.
$$
Expanding, you end up with
$$\require{cancel}
A^2 E^2 - 4 A^2 F - 2 A B D E + 4 A C D + B^2 D^2 - 4 B^2 F + 4 B C E - 4 C^2 = 0
$$
(remember we assumed $A\neq 0$).  So the four circles satisfy
\begin{align*}
D^2 - 4 F&=0 &&x\text{-axis}\colon y=0\\
E^2 - 4 F&=0 &&y\text{-axis}\colon x=0\\
\cancel{E^2 - 4 F} - 2 D E - 8 D + \cancel{D^2 - 4 F} - 8 E - 16&=0 &&x+y-2=0.\\
\end{align*}
*Id est*, we want to solve
\begin{align*}
D^2 - 4 F&=0\\
E^2 - 4 F&=0\\
D E + 4 D + 4 E + 8&=0.\\
\end{align*}
From the first two equations, we have $D^2=E^2=4F$, so $D=\pm E$.  Substituting into the third we have $D^2+8D+8=0$ (case $D=E$), or $-D^2+8=0$ (case $D=-E$). So we have $D=E=-4\pm2\sqrt2$ or $D=-E=\pm2\sqrt2$, hence $F=\frac14D^2=\dots$.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand the statement, there is one circle inside a triangle limited below by the $x$ axis, to the left by $y$ axis and by $y=2-x$ on the first quadrant (inside a triangle); there is another larger circle to the right limited on the left by the $y$ axis at the bottom by the $x$ axis and it is tangent to $y=2-x$ and the previous circle; another circle is on the 4th quadrant limited above by $x$ axis to the left by $y$ axis and it is tangent, say "north-east" to $y=2-x$. The last circle is on the 2nd quadrant and it is a obtained by the mirror image of the third circle an the line $y=x$. The centers of the circles are $C_1=(r_1,r_1)$, $C_2=(r_2,r_2)$, $C_3=(r_3,-r_3)$ and $C_4=(-r_4,r_4)$, where $r_i$ stands for the radius of the circle $i$. Notice that $r_3=r_4$.

It seems that you already know how to get the equation of the circles from the points of tangency. So, I won't discuss that.

One of the tangents for the first circle is determined by the intersection of the lines $y=x$ and $y=2-x$ at (1,1). The other tangents are $(r_1,0)$ and $(0,r_1)$, but you can get the radius by computing the distance to the first tangent point to the origin and dividing by 2.

For the second circle use the construction (Pythagoras) $r²_2+r²_2= \sqrt{1+1}+r_2$, where the square root comes from the distance of the tangent point along $y=x$ with the first circle. You can get a quadratic equation with only one solution satisfying the constraints. The other tangent points are $(r_2,0)$ and $(0,r_2)$.

For the third circle it is enough to notice that its center is along the line $y=-x$ which is parallel to $y=2-x$. The distance between these two lines is $\sqrt{2}$ (and that may be the radius). One of the tangent points is located at $x_{tan}=r_3+\sqrt{2} \: \cos(45)$ and $y_{tan}=-r_3+\sqrt{2}\: \sin(45)$, where the angle is measured counterclockwise from a horizontal line crossing the center of the circle. The other tangent points are $(r_3,0)$ and $(0,-r_3)$.

The last circle can be solved "mutatis mutandis" from the expression for the third one.